# Is it right to use new operator inside C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, out-of-memory

```
class test{
  int value;
};
class sample{
  sample(){
    test *var = new test();
  }
};

int main(){
  sample foo;
  //what will happen here if sample constructor fails to allocate its memory?
}
```

Is it right to use the `new` operator inside a C++ constructor?
What will happen here if the `sample` constructor fails to allocate its memory?

Comment: An exception will be thrown.

Comment: ... Or nullptr is returned

Comment: @EdHeal, this isn't the `std::nothrow` overload call, and `operator new` isn't overloaded. So an exception, definitely an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what will happen here if sample constructor fails to allocate a memory?

It will throw a [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception and can be sanitized in `main()` by catching it:

```
int main() {
    try {
       sample foo;

        // Work with foo ...
    }
    catch(const std::bad_alloc& ba) {
        std::err << "Not enough memory available. Caught 'bad_alloc' exception: '" 
                 << ba.what() << "'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`new` will throw a `bad_alloc` exception upon failure.

When a constructor exits by exception, the object never reaches the point of being constructed. Its destructor does not run.

If the exception is thrown within the constructor body, all the object's member variables get destroyed (by destructor calls). If the exception is thrown from the constructor of a member, then the preceding members' destructors run. The point is to undo whatever the constructor has done so far, no more and no less.

There shouldn't be anything smelly about any of this. Do take care that member destructors will always behave properly. This may involve being more fastidious about class invariants. C++ wants to take care of exceptional conditions so you don't need to write a lot of corner cases… but the flip side is that the corner cases still exist, implicit and unspoken.